# How to add more url to the proxy except list on win10

Tags: networking, windows-10, proxy

in win10 the text area for the proxy except list seems there is a limit (260 characters), after copied half of my settings from my win7, I could not type in any letters.

Anyone knows how to add more url to the list.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer my own question. To do that, you need to set it in ie 11 settings. not ie edge.[image]